# Google map controls not localized if language is set to english (IE only)

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, localization

I have problem with google map localization (IE only has this problem).
Somehow it is not localized properly if I set language to English (it displays text in my local language).

Maybe you have the same problem? Please try:

Go to google's changing map language example:
https://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_language/map_lang.html
Set language to English and hover over arrow control. 
My result:
[image: IE10 badly translated tooltips on google map]

Hovewer if I change the language to German, everything is OK:
[image: Correct translations for German language]

I know that there are settings in browsers for selecting prefered languages. I removed Polish completely and left only English language in browser settings. I also read about changing google map language directly from their site:

> For example, to display a Maps API application in Japanese, add &language=ja to the script tag as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ja">
```

So all you have to do is set language="whateverLanguage" and according to:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?hl=pl#Localization
it should work. And it works... except for English language. I inspected source of website after applying English to map and there is language=en in script tag. So why it doesn't work for English and it works for all other languages? Even Australian and Great Britain English is working. But for language=en or language=en-US i have Polish instead... and only for IE.